# Type error with options in Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()

Tags: typescript

The following code is causing a TypeScript error, but is working correctly:

```js
components.push(expirationDate.toLocaleDateString(undefined, { dateStyle: 'long' }));

Error:(31, 74) TS2345: Argument of type '{ dateStyle: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dateStyle' does not exist in type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
```

I do see that `dateStyle` is indeed not included in `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions` (which is the type for the options object:

```js
    toLocaleDateString(locales?: string | string[], options?: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions): string;
    ...
    interface DateTimeFormatOptions {
        localeMatcher?: string;
        weekday?: string;
        era?: string;
        year?: string;
        month?: string;
        day?: string;
        hour?: string;
        minute?: string;
        second?: string;
        timeZoneName?: string;
        formatMatcher?: string;
        hour12?: boolean;
        timeZone?: string;
    }
```

So, is there any way to fix this error without simply using `//@ts-ignore`?

Comment: Why are you insisting to input the `dateStyle: long` property if the object doesn't use it?

Comment: It does use it, that's the thing. It's just not defined in the type. 
`date.toLocaleDateString() ==='6/30/2021'`...`date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, { dateStyle: 'long' })) === 'June 30, 2021'`

Answer (score 4):

Typescript appears to have added the `dateStyle` options amongst others in v4.2.

Here's the PR that introduced them: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41880.

Upgrading to v4.2.3 fixed the Typescript error for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting this issue in the future, you might need to have a more recent version of Ecmascript specified in your tsconfig.

My understanding is that these options did not exist in earlier revisions of the language.

What fixed it for me was changing:

```
    "lib": [
      "es2017",...
```

to

```
    "lib": [
      "es2020",...
```

in my `tsconfig.json` file